# Global XState context using React useContext hook

Tags: reactjs, xstate

Having some issues to implement XState in my app. I want to use the useContext for global context management together with XState to manage different workflows of the app.

I'm trying to implement a use case consisting in a **Modal launching a fetch request** on confirmation and **returning the result**. The process is:

1. Open the Modal
2. Submit the request
3. Get the result

I've set the state machine with the different states (idle, loading, failure, success) and wire it up in two ways

1. Launching the modal calling useMachine directly and passing send/state as props to the Modal - This works
2. Launching the modal which grabs the machine from useContext - in the example below, when clickin submit, the service is triggered however nothing is returned back.

I've also set a codesandbox with the both cases.
[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-rgb-7hv1lw)

[image: Edit nervous-rgb-7hv1lw]

I want to achieve the same functionality of 1 in 2, what am I missing here?

App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import { GlobalStateProvider } from "./globalState";
import ModalWithProps from "./ModalWithProps";
import ModalGlobal from "./ModalGlobal";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <GlobalStateProvider>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>XState Global Context</h1>
        <h2>Modal With Props</h2>
        <p>After submitting, the feedback is received</p>
        <ModalWithProps />
        <br />
        <h2>Modal With Global Context</h2>
        <p>After submitting, there is no feedback</p>
          <ModalGlobal />
      </div>
    </GlobalStateProvider>
  );
}
```

endcall.js (xstate machine)

```
import { createMachine, assign } from "xstate";

const retryCond = (ctx, evt) => ctx.retries < 3;

const fetchUser = () => {
  console.log("Fetching User");
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("Message sent.");
    }, 1000);
  });
};

export const endCallModalMachine = createMachine({
  id: "modal",
  initial: "idle",
  context: {
    message: undefined,
    retries: 0
  },
  states: {
    idle: {
      on: {
        OPEN: "open"
      }
    },
    open: {
      on: {
        SUBMIT: "loading",
        CLOSE: "idle"
      }
    },
    loading: {
      invoke: {
        src: (ctx, evt) => fetchUser(),
        onDone: {
          target: "success",
          actions: assign({
            message: (ctx, evt) => evt.data
          })
        },
        onError: "failure"
      }
    },
    success: {
      on: {
        CLOSE: {
          target: "idle",
          actions: assign({
            message: () => undefined
          })
        }
      }
    },
    failure: {
      on: {
        RETRY: {
          target: "loading",
          cond: retryCond,
          actions: assign({
            retries: (context, event) => context.retries + 1
          })
        },
        CLOSE: {
          target: "idle",
          actions: assign({
            retries: (context, event) => 0
          })
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

export default endCallModalMachine;
```

globalState.jsx

```
import React, { createContext } from "react";
import { useInterpret } from "@xstate/react";
import { endCallModalMachine } from "./endcall";
export const GlobalStateContext = createContext({});

export const GlobalStateProvider = (props) => {
  const modalService = useInterpret(endCallModalMachine);

  return (
    <GlobalStateContext.Provider value={{ modalService }}>
      {props.children}
    </GlobalStateContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

ModalGlobal.jsx

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { GlobalStateContext } from "./globalState";
import { useSelector } from "@xstate/react";

const evt = {
  CLOSE: "CLOSE",
  SUBMIT: "SUBMIT",
  RETRY: "RETRY"
};

const buttonText = (value, message) => {
  switch (value) {
    case "open":
      return "submit";
    case "failure":
      return "retry";
    case "success":
      return message;
    default:
      return value;
  }
};

const modalSelector = (state) => {
  return !state.matches("idle");
};

export default function ModalContainer() {
  const globalServices = useContext(GlobalStateContext);
  const { send } = globalServices.modalService;
  const isModalOpen = useSelector(globalServices.modalService, modalSelector);

  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          send({ type: "OPEN" });
        }}
      >
        Launch
      </button>
      {isModalOpen && <Modal />}
    </>
  );
}

function Modal() {
  const globalServices = useContext(GlobalStateContext);
  const { send, state } = globalServices.modalService;

  const handleClose = () => {
    send({ type: evt.CLOSE });
  };
  const handleSubmit = () => send({ type: evt.SUBMIT });
  const handleRetry = () => send({ type: evt.RETRY });

  return (
    <>
      <div className="xmodal">
        <button onClick={handleClose}>close</button>
        <h1>Modal</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur ea
          aperiam eveniet sint necessitatibus. Rem, odio? Placeat, doloremque!
          Velit fugit quisquam ex debitis!
        </p>
        {state.context.retries >= 3 && (
          <p className="error">
            The message could not be sent, please try again later
          </p>
        )}
        <button
          disabled={state.context.retries > 2}
          onClick={() =>
            state.value === "failure" ? handleRetry() : handleSubmit()
          }
        >
          {buttonText(state.value, state.context.message)}
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

ModalWithProps.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { useMachine } from "@xstate/react";
import modalMachine from "./endcall";

const evt = {
  CLOSE: "CLOSE",
  SUBMIT: "SUBMIT",
  RETRY: "RETRY"
};

const buttonText = (value, message) => {
  switch (value) {
    case "open":
      return "submit";
    case "failure":
      return "retry";
    case "success":
      return message;
    default:
      return value;
  }
};

export default function ModalContainer() {
  const [state, send] = useMachine(modalMachine, { devTools: false });
  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          send({ type: "OPEN" });
        }}
      >
        Launch
      </button>
      {state.value !== "idle" && <Modal state={state} send={send} />}
    </>
  );
}

function Modal({ send, state }) {
  const handleClose = () => {
    send({ type: evt.CLOSE });
  };
  const handleSubmit = () => send({ type: evt.SUBMIT });
  const handleRetry = () => send({ type: evt.RETRY });

  return (
    <>
      hey
      <div className="xmodal">
        <button onClick={handleClose}>close</button>
        <h1>Modal</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur ea
          aperiam eveniet sint necessitatibus. Rem, odio? Placeat, doloremque!
          Velit fugit quisquam ex debitis!
        </p>
        {state.context.retries >= 3 && (
          <p className="error">
            The message could not be sent, please try again later
          </p>
        )}
        <button
          disabled={state.context.retries > 2}
          onClick={() =>
            state.value === "failure" ? handleRetry() : handleSubmit()
          }
        >
          {buttonText(state.value, state.context.message)}
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem comes from the way you consume the `globalService` in your `ModalGlobal` component.

In the `ModalContainer`, after retrieving the service from the context, you are interpreting it by using the `useSelector` hook.

However, you are missing this part in the `Modal` component and that leaves you unsubscribed to the service changes. You can try it by using the `useActor` hook:

```
  // const { send, state } = globalServices.modalService;
  const [state, send] = useActor(globalServices.modalService);
```